# collectd data not showing in influxdb container

Tags: linux, docker, monitoring, influxdb, collectd

I'm trying to in place a global resource monitoring of a small cluster. The chosen stack:
- collectd on the node for data gathering
- influxdb as backend using the official docker container
- grafana as frontend again using the official container
The container are launched on a central server. Grafana is able to connect to influxdb source and I updated collectd agent (network plugin in collectd.conf) and influxdb (influxdb.conf with collectd plugin) to enable them to talk to each others.

But no data is showing up... No much log to check, but for sure the influxdb data file are empty and nothing comes up when querying.

Anyone experienced such context? Any idea where to dig?

collectd conf extract:

```
# /etc/collectd/collectd.conf
<Plugin network>
   Server "<public_IP_of_the_docker_host>" "25826"
</Plugin>
```

influxdb conf:

```
[input_plugins.collectd]
enabled = true
address = "public_IP_of_the_docker_host"
port = 25826
database = "collectd"
typesdb = "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"
```

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using the official docker container with grafana 3.0.1